# Add certain filters before passing to "git diff"

Tags: git, diff

Is it possible to apply certain filters, say "fmt -w 80" for file, before the diffs shown in "git diff"? Thus lines can automatically break when I want to see the diff.

The following is an example passing through `fmt -w 20`.

Original file

```
This is a very very very long line.
```

Modified file

```
This is a very very very very long line.
```

Regular results:

```
-This is a very very very long line.
+This is a very very very very long line.
```

After passing through the filter:

```
 This is a very very
-very long line.
+very very long line.
```

P.S. I know `git diff --color-words` can show the difference of words, but I just want to see it line by line.

Comment: not sure I understand, you want to apply the filter on the file before the diff, or on the result of the diff? maybe you can mock some output to make it clear.

Comment: @OznOg Before the diff. See my edits.

Comment: the probelm her is that you have a `\n` at the end of `This is a very very` which should not be here... I'm not sure that would give the output you expect as the diff would not be 'standard'